# SSRS Datasources on the server

Tags: reporting-services

I am about to start a new SSRS project. I have some experience with SSRS and in the past, I used to create my datasource and deploy it to server. Every time I wanted to work on my report, I had the DS locally. My new project has to use a datasource stored on the SSRS server, on datasources folder. How do I map my project to use that DS from server? I am usingSQL Server Data tools for visual studio 2013.Thanks

Comment: Can you replicate the server environment locally or are you testing on the production server?

Comment: I am trying to build the report locally and then deploy it. I am able to build a brand new datasource, but I don't want to deploy it, since it already exists on the server

Answer (score 0):

you can't. In the report project properties, you have some deployment options. one is to not overwrite data sources. So the easiest is to have a data source named the same in your report, which will not get deployed.

once the report is deployed, you can change it's data source in report manager (the web portal), if you need to.

Comment: Thanks, I will try that. So, as far as I understood, I have to create a data source locally with same name of the one in the server, and then, once I deploy it, it will use that datasource on the server, is that correct?

Comment: almost, there is a TargetDataSourcesFolder setting in the project settings as well. if there is already a datasource on the server with the same name in this folder, and the OverwriteDataSource setting is set to false, it won't get overwritten,

Comment: Yes, I am aware of this setting and indeed it is set to false, I don't want to overwrite it, but use it as my datasource. SO I think I am ready to go, I will try it and let you know.

Comment: SOrry, I still had not chance to try this, I am waiting for the server administration to give me a permission to do that, I am currently working with Report Builder, which is the oficial tool used here