# Can not find the existing data source for the SSRS report

Tags: sql-server-2005, reporting-services, ssrs-2008

I am trying to create a SSRS report with sql server 2005 BI. I have to use the existing data source to be consistent with the other reports, but in the SharedDataSources folder when I click add existing item, I cant find the Data source.
Can someone tell me where the Data Sources for SSRS reports store physically on a machine?

Thanks

Comment: Data Source not physically stored by SSRS. it stored in Database and if you didn't find the data source then execute your report builder "run as Administrator". or check the user has permission "System Administrator" on SSRS report server .

Comment: i think that's the same question:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28220262/ssrs-datasources-on-the-server/28235885#28235885

Answer (score 0):

It should be stored in the SSRS project. It will appear as .rds file.

[image]

Comment: That's what I am missing. I was able to export it from db but I get xml error in data source when I use that.